# Is there any way to configure the “ADVANCED DATA SECURITY” option in Azure SQL through Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-sql-server

I would like to add the “ADVANCED DATA SECURITY” option in Azure SQL through Terraform. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Just from the Azure document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/advanced-data-security#1-enable-ads, it only provides the way that configure it on Portal. We searched and didn't find the way to add "ADVANCED DATA SECURITY" option in Azure SQL through Terraform. I think it's impossible.

Comment: Could it be done with a Powershell script post the main database deployment?

Comment: yes through powershell script we can do it  but i am trying to find a way to do through terraform

Comment: @Anand We may suppose that it's not  possible.